# docker で make npm ができない

Tags: docker, laravel, npm

## 環境

mac M1チップ
os bigsur

## 内容

[React x LaravelのSPAで作るチュートリアル①(環境構築編)](https://qiita.com/morry_48/items/abd620f051fb4f36dcc2)

を参考にdockerでlaravelとreactの開発環境を構築しています。

上記リンクの通りに進めて [Reactの環境構築](https://qiita.com/morry_48/items/abd620f051fb4f36dcc2#react%E3%81%AE%E7%92%B0%E5%A2%83%E6%A7%8B%E7%AF%89) の部分の手前までは問題なくできたのですが、
`make npm` を実行すると以下のエラーが出ました。

```
make: *** No rule to make target `npm'.  Stop.
```

Makefileに不備があると思い、以下の通り修正しました。

**修正前:**

```
up:
    docker compose up -d
build:
    docker compose build --no-cache --force-rm
laravel-install:
    docker compose exec app composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel .
create-project:
    mkdir -p src
    @make build
    @make up
    @make laravel-install
    docker compose exec app php artisan key:generate
    docker compose exec app php artisan storage:link
    docker compose exec app chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
    @make fresh
install-recommend-packages:
    docker compose exec app composer require doctrine/dbal
    docker compose exec app composer require --dev ucan-lab/laravel-dacapo
    docker compose exec app composer require --dev barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
    docker compose exec app composer require --dev beyondcode/laravel-dump-server
    docker compose exec app composer require --dev barryvdh/laravel-debugbar
    docker compose exec app composer require --dev roave/security-advisories:dev-master
    docker compose exec app php artisan vendor:publish --provider="BeyondCode\DumpServer\DumpServerServiceProvider"
    docker compose exec app php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider"
init:
    docker compose up -d --build
    docker compose exec app composer install
    docker compose exec app cp .env.example .env
    docker compose exec app php artisan key:generate
    docker compose exec app php artisan storage:link
    docker compose exec app chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
    @make fresh
remake:
    @make destroy
    @make init
stop:
    docker compose stop
down:
    docker compose down --remove-orphans
down-v:
    docker compose down --remove-orphans --volumes
restart:
    @make down
    @make up
destroy:
    docker compose down --rmi all --volumes --remove-orphans
ps:
    docker compose ps
logs:
    docker compose logs
logs-watch:
    docker compose logs --follow
log-web:
    docker compose logs web
log-web-watch:
    docker compose logs --follow web
log-app:
    docker compose logs app
log-app-watch:
    docker compose logs --follow app
log-db:
    docker compose logs db
log-db-watch:
    docker compose logs --follow db
web:
    docker compose exec web bash
app:
    docker compose exec app bash
migrate:
    docker compose exec app php artisan migrate
fresh:
    docker compose exec app php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
seed:
    docker compose exec app php artisan db:seed
dacapo:
    docker compose exec app php artisan dacapo
rollback-test:
    docker compose exec app php artisan migrate:fresh
    docker compose exec app php artisan migrate:refresh
tinker:
    docker compose exec app php artisan tinker
test:
    docker compose exec app php artisan test
optimize:
    docker compose exec app php artisan optimize
optimize-clear:
    docker compose exec app php artisan optimize:clear
cache:
    docker compose exec app composer dump-autoload -o
    @make optimize
    docker compose exec app php artisan event:cache
    docker compose exec app php artisan view:cache
cache-clear:
    docker compose exec app composer clear-cache
    @make optimize-clear
    docker compose exec app php artisan event:clear
db:
    docker compose exec db bash
sql:
    docker compose exec db bash -c 'mysql -u $$MYSQL_USER -p$$MYSQL_PASSWORD $$MYSQL_DATABASE'
redis:
    docker compose exec redis redis-cli
ide-helper:
    docker compose exec app php artisan clear-compiled
    docker compose exec app php artisan ide-helper:generate
    docker compose exec app php artisan ide-helper:meta
    docker compose exec app php artisan ide-helper:models --nowrite
```

**修正後:**

```
up:
    docker-compose up -d
build:
    docker-compose build --no-cache --force-rm
laravel-install:
    docker-compose exec app composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel .
create-project:
    @make build
    @make up
    @make laravel-install
    docker-compose exec app php artisan key:generate
    docker-compose exec app php artisan storage:link
    docker-compose exec app chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
    @make fresh
install-recommend-packages:
    docker-compose exec app composer require doctrine/dbal "^2"
    docker-compose exec app composer require --dev ucan-lab/laravel-dacapo
    docker-compose exec app composer require --dev barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper
    docker-compose exec app composer require --dev beyondcode/laravel-dump-server
    docker-compose exec app composer require --dev barryvdh/laravel-debugbar
    docker-compose exec app composer require --dev roave/security-advisories:dev-master
    docker-compose exec app php artisan vendor:publish --provider="BeyondCode\DumpServer\DumpServerServiceProvider"
    docker-compose exec app php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Barryvdh\Debugbar\ServiceProvider"
init:
    docker-compose up -d --build
    docker-compose exec app composer install
    docker-compose exec app cp .env.example .env
    docker-compose exec app php artisan key:generate
    docker-compose exec app php artisan storage:link
    docker-compose exec app chmod -R 777 storage bootstrap/cache
    @make fresh
remake:
    @make destroy
    @make init
stop:
    docker-compose stop
down:
    docker-compose down --remove-orphans
restart:
    @make down
    @make up
destroy:
    docker-compose down --rmi all --volumes --remove-orphans
destroy-volumes:
    docker-compose down --volumes --remove-orphans
ps:
    docker-compose ps
logs:
    docker-compose logs
logs-watch:
    docker-compose logs --follow
log-web:
    docker-compose logs web
log-web-watch:
    docker-compose logs --follow web
log-app:
    docker-compose logs app
log-app-watch:
    docker-compose logs --follow app
log-db:
    docker-compose logs db
log-db-watch:
    docker-compose logs --follow db
web:
    docker-compose exec web ash
app:
    docker-compose exec app bash
migrate:
    docker-compose exec app php artisan migrate
fresh:
    docker-compose exec app php artisan migrate:fresh --seed
seed:
    docker-compose exec app php artisan db:seed
dacapo:
    docker-compose exec app php artisan dacapo
rollback-test:
    docker-compose exec app php artisan migrate:fresh
    docker-compose exec app php artisan migrate:refresh
tinker:
    docker-compose exec app php artisan tinker
test:
    docker-compose exec app php artisan test
optimize:
    docker-compose exec app php artisan optimize
optimize-clear:
    docker-compose exec app php artisan optimize:clear
cache:
    docker-compose exec app composer dump-autoload -o
    @make optimize
    docker-compose exec app php artisan event:cache
    docker-compose exec app php artisan view:cache
cache-clear:
    docker-compose exec app composer clear-cache
    @make optimize-clear
    docker-compose exec app php artisan event:clear
npm:
    @make npm-install
npm-install:
    docker-compose exec web npm install
npm-dev:
    docker-compose exec web npm run dev
npm-watch:
    docker-compose exec web npm run watch
npm-watch-poll:
    docker-compose exec web npm run watch-poll
npm-hot:
    docker-compose exec web npm run hot
yarn:
    docker-compose exec web yarn
yarn-install:
    @make yarn
yarn-dev:
    docker-compose exec web yarn dev
yarn-watch:
    docker-compose exec web yarn watch
yarn-watch-poll:
    docker-compose exec web yarn watch-poll
yarn-hot:
    docker-compose exec web yarn hot
db:
    docker-compose exec db bash
sql:
    docker-compose exec db bash -c 'mysql -u $$MYSQL_USER -p$$MYSQL_PASSWORD $$MYSQL_DATABASE'
redis:
    docker-compose exec redis redis-cli
ide-helper:
    docker-compose exec app php artisan clear-compiled
    docker-compose exec app php artisan ide-helper:generate
    docker-compose exec app php artisan ide-helper:meta
    docker-compose exec app php artisan ide-helper:models --nowrite
```

再度 `make npm` を実行すると以下のエラーが出ます。

```
docker-compose exec web npm install
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "npm": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
make[1]: *** [npm-install] Error 126
make: *** [npm] Error 2
```

調べても原因がわからず前に進めない状態です。
何が原因かわかる方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか？よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: まず `npm` コマンドが使える状態になっているかを `which npm` 等で確認してみてください。 / 参照している記事では手順を簡略化するために Makefile を使用しているようですが、Dokcer に make コマンドが必須なわけではありません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。which npmを実行してみたのですが```/Users/（ユーザー名）/.nodebrew/current/bin/npm```にありました。プロジェクト内に無いのでエラーが出ていると言う事でしょうか？